# PyMongo returns an empty result set when a MongoDB client returns correct results

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a simple **MongoDB** collection that I am accessing using `PyMongo` in my **Python** script.

I am filtering the query in **Python** using the dictionary:

```
{ "$and" : [
    { "bettinginterests" : { "$elemMatch" : { "runner.name" : "Jailhouse King" } } },
    { "bettinginterests" : { "$elemMatch" : { "runner.name" : "Tyrone Haji" } } }
    ]
}
```

And this returns correct results. However, I would like to expand the filter to be:

```
{ "$and" : [
    { "bettinginterests" : { "$elemMatch" : { "runner.name" : "Jailhouse King" } } },
    { "bettinginterests" : { "$elemMatch" : { "runner.name" : "Tyrone Haji" } } },
    { "summary.dist" : "1" }
    ]
}
```

And this is returning an empty result set. Now when I do this same query in my **MongoDB** client using:

```
db.race_results.find({ "$and" : [
    { "bettinginterests" : { "$elemMatch" : { "runner.name" : "Jailhouse King" } } },
    { "bettinginterests" : { "$elemMatch" : { "runner.name" : "Tyrone Haji" } } },
    { "summary.dist": "1" }
    ]
})
```

The results are returned correctly as expected.

I don't see any difference between the **Python** dictionary being passed as the query filter, and the `js` code being executed on my **MongoDB** client.

Does anyone see where there might be a difference? I'm at a loss here.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a sample record in my DB:
https://gist.github.com/brspurri/8cefcd20a7f995145a81

**UPDATE 2:**
Python Code to perform the query:

```
runner = "Jailhouse King"
opponent = "Tyrone Haji"
query_filter = {"$and": [
                    {"bettinginterests": {"$elemMatch": {"runner.name": runner}}},
                    {"bettinginterests": {"$elemMatch": {"runner.name": opponent}}},
                    { "summary.dist" : "1" }
                    ]
                }

try:
    collection = db.databases['race_results']
    entities = None
    if not query_filter:
        entities = collection.find().sort([("date", -1)])
    else:
        entities = collection.find(query_filter).sort([("date", -1)])

except BaseException, e:
    print('An error occured in query: %s\n' % e)
```

Comment: Just to make sure - you are definitely putting `$and` and `$elemMatch` into quotes, right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I manually copied from my python dictionary, so I missed them. But they are there indeed. Updated now.

Comment: Thanks, well, sanity check, are you sure you are executing the queries against the same database?

Comment: Yup. Queries work in both PyMongo and a MongoDB client until I add the `{"summary.dist" : "1" }` line, in which case it works in my client, but not in PyMongo.

Comment: Which mongo version are you use?

Comment: @Brett, can you show your python code how you *actually*  query the collection? It could be something unrelated to the query itself.

Comment: Updated with the python code calling the query.

Answer (score 1):

This line is probably the culprit.

```
collection = db.databases['race_results']
```

If `db` is your database you are doing it wrong. It should be

```
collection = db['race_results']
```

Comment: and the try / catch is misleading u to the query.